# How do I make a single ArrayList that has two values, one a String and one an int?

Tags: java, arraylist

My friend made a "game" where he let you choose swords and stuff using a bunch of if - else statements. I am trying to top him by making a text based game where a random monster spawns from an ArrayList. Each monster needs to have a name and an hp value. I need to be able to pick a random monster and I would like to make it so I can scramble the ArrayList using:

```
Collections.shuffle(Monster);
```

I have made a multi-dimensional Array before but I'm not sure how to make an ArrayList with two values for each spot place.

Here is my attempt at it so far:

```
List<String> Inventory = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<double[]> Monsters = new ArrayList<double[]>(2);
    List<String> Monster = new ArrayList<String>();

    Monster.add("Goblin");
    Monster.add("Josh");
    Monster.add("Gremlin");
    Monster.add("Unicorn");
    Monster.add("Possesed Elf");
    Monster.add("Shmorple");

    // Can I use Monsters.add(Monster);?
```

EDIT: I finished the game and I ended up learning how to use classes to make objects; thank you everyone who suggested it. I have learned quite a bit just off a few responses!

Comment: Create a class to encapsulate both values and add instances to your list.

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions; especially when posting on public forums. In Java variables are **always** in `camelCase` - `PascalCase` is reserved for classes.

Comment: Note that `List<double[]>` is not possible in Java (at least currently) as `double` is a **primitive datatype**. You need to use its wrapper class `Double` instead.

Comment: @Zabuza As I recall, `double[]` is a valid type argument. Arrays themselves are reference types, even if the array is for primitive values.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Indeed, you are right. I'm reverting my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are familiar with classes (but if you use Java you should).

So, what you want is to randomly pick a monster from a list thus you first need to model the "Monster" class.
Since you said that each monster has a name (a String) and life (an Integer), you can create the following class:

```
public class Monster
{
    private String name;
    private int hp;

    public Monster(String name, int hp)
    {
          this.name = name;
          this.hp = hp;
    }
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public int getHP(){return hp;}

}
```

At this point you can create your list of Monster:

```
List<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can now populate it as follows:

```
monsters.add(new Monster("Goblin", 10));
monsters.add(new Monster("Possesed Elf", 40));
```

etc...

You can now exploit

```
Collection.shuffle(monsters);
Monster randomMonster = monsters.get(0);
System.out.println("Random monster appear: " + randomMonster.getName());
```

And remember that you should follow Java best practice and to name variables and methods by following the cammel-case style (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Comment: This would've been really helpful for beginning programmer me! Too bad I forgot about this question shortly after because someone in my APCS class taught me about classes and objects. Sorry your answer went to waste because I didn't understand OOP!

Answer (score 5):

If the integer and String value has a one-to-one mapping relation, you can use an ArrayList of HashMap.

If not, you can just create a new class with those 2 attributes and use an ArrayList to hold the objects created from that class.

```
public class Monster{
    private int health;
    private String name;
}

List<Monster> monsterList = new ArrayList<>();

Collections.shuffle(monsterList);  //to shuffle it
```

Answer (score 0):

Array stores objects that are the same type, so technically you cannot do this. However, the object is a monster here, so either you array of monsters and shuffle from that list like so:

`List<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<>()` where Monster is an object that holds individual's properties

or

use Pair from `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple` package, so you have

`List<Pair<String, Integer>> monsters = new ArrayList<>()
monsters.add(Pair.of("monster_name", 20));`